# Как добавить в игру переключение языков геймплея? Юнити / Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я сделал игру на русском языке. Допустим, я хочу, чтобы весь текст в игре пользователь мог изменить на тот, который ему нравится. Как наиболее правильно это сделать? Просто изменять весь текст на сцене при ее загрузке или есть какие-то уже готовые решения?

Comment: _Как наиболее правильно это сделать?_ А из каких вариантов вы выбираете?

Comment: 1 json файл на 1 язык -> переключать файлы, когда надо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если говорить о правильном изменении в реальном времени, это должна быть событийная модель, что-бы каждый элемент мог бы сразу отреагировать.

```
public enum Languages { EN, RU }

public delegate void ChangeLanguage (Languages language);

public class Language { // Singleton

    public ChangeLanguage Change; // Событие изменения языка
    private static Language instance;
    private Languages _current;

    public static Language getInstance () {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Language();
        return instance;
    }

    public Languages Current {
        get { return _current; }
        set {
            // Факт изменения языка, сообщение о событии, сохранение
            _current = value;
            if (Change != null)
                Change.Invoke(_current);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("language", (int)_current);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
        }
    }

    private Language () {
        _current = (Languages)PlayerPrefs.GetInt("language");
    }
}
```

---

```
public class UILanguageElement : MonoBehaviour {

    private void Awake () {
        // Подписка на событие
        Language.getInstance().Change += ChangeLanguage;
        ChangeLanguage(Language.getInstance().Current);
    }

    // срабатывает при смене Language.getInstance().Current = Languages.RU;
    private void ChangeLanguage (Languages language) {
        switch (language) {

        }
    }
}
```

---

Что касается хранения, как вариант можно через `ScriptableObject`

(Создаются через <kbd>Right Click</kbd> / <kbd>Create</kbd> / <kbd>Language Data</kbd>, как создать материал или скрипт)

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "LanguageData", menuName = "Language Data")]

public class LanguageData : ScriptableObject {
    // Языки в массиве LanguageData по порядку enum Languages
    public string[] Text = new string[2];
}
```

Хронить для удобства все `LanguageData` в отдельной папке и подключать к `UILanguageElement` который тогда будет выглядеть так:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;

[DisallowMultipleComponent]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Text))]

public class UILanguageElement : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private Text _text;
    [SerializeField] private LanguageData _data;

    private void Awake () {
        if (_text == null)
            _text = GetComponent<Text>();
        Language.getInstance().Change += ChangeLanguage;
        ChangeLanguage(Language.getInstance().Current);
    }

    private void ChangeLanguage (Languages language) {
        if (_text != null && _data != null && _data.Text != null) {
            int LanguageNumber = (int)language;
            if (_data.Text.Length >= LanguageNumber && _data.Text[LanguageNumber] != "") {
                _text.text = _data.Text[LanguageNumber];
                return;
            }
            // Если текст для данного языка отсутствует то устанавливается английский
            if (_data.Text.Length >= 0 && _data.Text[0] != "")
                _text.text = _data.Text[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Либо хранить в `json`, или даже `txt`, если не страшен парсинг.

Comment: Вопрос скорее технический, а не по теме, но все же: как вы поставили разделяющую линию между первыми двумя отрезками кода? Или она ставится сама, когда пишется два куса

Comment: @МаксимФисман, жмякаем по волшебной кнопке <kbd>править</kbd> и созерцаем.

Comment: Нет-нет, я имею ввиду не обводку слов RightClick/Create/LanguageData, а просто серую линию между class Language и class UILanguageElement

Comment: Кстати, сейчас разбираю ваш ответ, пытаюсь применить, но у меня нет варианта LanguageData после Create

Comment: @МаксимФисман и не будет, пока вы не пропишети `CreateAssetMenu`. (следующий блок кода)

Comment: То есть нужно создать обычный C# класс, а в нем прописать ```[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "LanguageData", menuName = "Language Data")] ```и все остальное. Или где вы имеете ввиду нужно прописать этот блок?

Comment: То есть вам совсем в лом, для начала проверить, что вы сами написали, ну или загуглить, что это за непонятный такой `ScriptableObject ` и с чем его едят...

Comment: Я знаю, что ScriptableObject - это не объект и не скрипт, а код в классе. Именно поэтому я и запутался, потому что вы акцентировали внимание на то, что его нужно создавать как-то по особенному.  Ну, в общем теперь я понял, что мы друг друга не поняли, но теперь я уже понял. В общем спасибо, буду разбираться дальше

Comment: LOL. Я не видел ни одного, гайда/дока, где описывая `ScriptableObject ` не описывали, как создать экземпляр этого объекта... то есть `CreateAssetMenu`... таких нет. Как вы можете знать об одном, не зная о другом... ОК. Разбираться самому, это всегда хорошо. LOL.

Comment: А где я должен вызывать метод ChangeLanguage из класса UILanguageElement,если у меня например есть Dropdown, в котором можно изменять языки? Куда я должен повесить UILanguageElement и как вызывать в нем метод ChangeLanguage(). Вроде как с помощью фнкции OnChanged() вDropdown, но он не видит этого метода, наверное потому что у этого метода параметром является (Languages language)

Comment: Да. Разрабатываешь игру на одном языка, а в конце добавляя языки и переводы не придётся носиться по всему проекту и коду в поисках, всё можно хранить в одном каталоге в виде `ScriptableObject`. Тупо заходишь в какой нибудь каталог типа ~`Language/Interface/MainMenu` и идёшь по списку этих оъектов типа `Play`, `Options`, `Market`... и т.д. `ChangeLanguage` подписан на `event Change`, он вызывается сам при `Language.getInstance().Current = Languages.RU;`.

Comment: В итоге, у меня есть dropdown с языками: английский, русский... Каким образом мне заставить игру, чтобы при клике на, например, русский, все тексты менялись с английского на русский?

Comment: Ну напиши обработчик этого `Dropdown`, событие изменения этого значения уже вшито (https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Dropdown-onValueChanged.html). В чём тут проблема? Можно даже автозаполнение `dropdown.options` по списку `enum Languages` написать (https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Dropdown-options.html). `enum` это на самом деле `int[]` притворяющийся строками.

Comment: Окей,  я обавлю обработчик OnValueChanged: мне нужно указать объект, скрипт на объекте и метод в этом скрипте

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111643/discussion-between---and-yaroslav).